# Permission error using GPS

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, permissions, location

I want to get back the position of my phone but I have a problem with this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,0,(LocationListener) this);
```

I know the problem is the permission check but I don't know to do this in my code:

```
package com.cmn.cmnvtc;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainPageFragment1 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {


    LocationManager locationManager;
    public LatLng myLocation;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main1, container, false);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,0,(LocationListener) this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(48.9818555, 2.270541);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 15));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Le garage").position(marker));
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + " - Longitude:" + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

How can I do this , please?

My error is in the code : "Add permission check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check it for **Marshmollow**

```
private static final int GRANTED = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

if (checkCoarseLocationPermission(getActivity()) &&  checkFineLocationPermission(getActivity())) {
        //permissions are granted
    }else {
        requestLocationPermission(getActivity());
    }
}

public boolean checkCoarseLocationPermission(Activity mActivity){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return permissionCheck == GRANTED;
}

public boolean checkFineLocationPermission(Activity mActivity){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    return permissionCheck == GRANTED;
}

public void requestLocationPermission(Activity mActivity){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
}
```

Comment: In methods checkCoarseLocationPermission, checkFineLocationPermission and requestLocationPermission, the IDE don't find permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and  ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION

Comment: you must import android.Manifest and not your package local manifest

Comment: MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION doesn't exist

Comment: this is just int,
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 11223;

Answer (score 0):

try this
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null){
 location = locationManager                                 .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + " - Longitude:" + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the permissions in the manifest of your app. Open your manifest.xml and put this two lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION allows your app to track the user position using the actual GPS.
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION allows your app to track the user position using WiFi Networks, so you can omit this one if you are only using the GPS.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work, there is the same problem

Comment: That's an IDE message. Have you tried to run the program?

Comment: No but I know it doesn't work. My phone runs Android 6